# How to achieve the exact behaviour of grunt processhtml in webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to place my webpack bundled files in the index.html like below:
How to achieve it?

```
<!-- build:css:prod app/assets/css/style.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="non-minified.css">
<!-- /build -->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to render your `index.html`. It includes all the JavaScript and CSS files in your `document.head`. You can also specify your own template though I don't think that you can use this particular comment: `<!-- build:css:prod app/assets/css/style.min.css -->`

Comment: Hi Joannes,
Thanks for your input.
I used "html webpack plugin" But in my production mode, I need the bundled css or js should be inside the <!-- build:css:prod app/assets/css/style.min.css -->
Is there any way to customize?
Thanks!

Comment: If you need full control over the template, maybe the [Mini HTML Webpack plugin](https://github.com/styleguidist/mini-html-webpack-plugin) is a better choice. It lets you define a [template function](https://github.com/styleguidist/mini-html-webpack-plugin#custom-templates) which will be called with all the asset URLs. Then you do a `string.replace` to fill in the placeholders.

Comment: Could you please me know about development mode vs production mode?

Comment: How to point dist/index.html for production and dev mode when I run the site?
 What are the things to be considered for production mode and dev mode? 
 While minifying the css, I dont want the background-image:ulr() to be placed in dist folder.  I just want to use the same image with global path in css file.  How to achieve this?  Please provide your inputs?